# Make something after remember me authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

greetings all
i am using spring security 3.0.2
and i am using the following configuration for remember me

```
<http use-expressions="true" >  
         <remember-me  token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"
         token-validity-seconds="1209600"/>

<beans:bean id="tokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

and i want after the cookie has been authenticated, i redirect the user tome some handler or class or interceptor that does some logic, any ideas how to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Remember-me` authentication happens transparently when an access is made to a protected resource.  On successful authentication, the user is served the protected resource.  I guess appropriate logic can be put in the protected resource to do further processing/redirection.